# Getting "[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined." when trying to import without .vue

Tags: typescript, vue.js, webpack, vue-loader

I' having the issue, that I can't import components from vue file without writing appending the .vue

My project is a vue project with typescript and a class based setup. I'm having the script and template files separated (.ts and .vue files)

`example: import DashboardCard from "@/components/dashboard_card/DashboardCard";`

When I import the component without the .vue

`[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.`

This error is gone, when I include all the components with .vue. Now this won't be an issue when I would start a new project, but it now happens in an already existing project that is huge. I assume this has something to do with the resolving of the extensions (vue.config.js - resolve [.vue]. I'm having troubles to get into the differences between vue.config.js and webpack.config.js.

My vue.config.js looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  transpileDependencies: [
    "vuex-module-decorators",
  ],
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module
        .rule('po')
        .test(/\.vue$/)
        .use('vue')
        .loader('vue-loader')
        .options({
          esModule: false,
        })
  }
}
```

My babel.config.js looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    '@vue/app'
  ]
}
```

My tsconfig.json looks like this:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": [
      "webpack-env",
      "mocha",
      "node",
      "chai"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "files": ["./src/shims-vue.d.ts"]
}
```

My package.json looks like this

```
{
  "name": "project",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "serve:mock": "cross-env VUE_APP_API_URL=http://localhost:3000/ vue-cli-service serve",
    "mock": "ts-node --project ./tsconfig.mock.json ./src/mock/server",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint",
    "lint:fix": "npx tslint ./src/**/*.ts ./tests/**/*.ts ./src/**/*.tsx ./tests/**/*.tsx --fix",
    "test:e2e": "vue-cli-service test:e2e",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit",
    "test": "npm run test:unit && npm run test:e2e"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/chart.js": "^2.9.16",
    "@websanova/vue-auth": "^2.21.14-beta",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
    "camelcase-keys": "^5.0.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.7.3",
    "color": "^3.1.0",
    "core-js": "^3.6.4",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.2",
    "csv-kit": "^1.0.21",
    "element-ui": "^2.4.5",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.1",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.0",
    "jsdom": "^13.0.0",
    "json-server": "^0.16.1",
    "lodash.isequal": "^4.5.0",
    "lodash.snakecase": "^4.1.1",
    "mark.js": "^8.11.1",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.1",
    "nprogress": "^0.2.0",
    "papaparse": "^4.6.3",
    "path-to-regexp": "^2.4.0",
    "register-service-worker": "^1.7.1",
    "ts-node": "^8.8.1",
    "vue": "^2.5.17",
    "vue-axios": "^2.1.4",
    "vue-chartjs": "^3.5.0",
    "vue-class-component": "^6.0.0",
    "vue-echarts": "^4.0.1",
    "vue-i18n": "^8.15.6",
    "vue-i18n-plugin": "^0.2.2",
    "vue-loader": "^15.9.1",
    "vue-password-strength-meter": "^1.4.2",
    "vue-property-decorator": "^7.0.0",
    "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
    "vue-svgicon": "^3.2.1",
    "vue2-collapse": "^1.0.15",
    "vuex": "^3.0.1",
    "vuex-module-decorators": "^0.9.9",
    "zxcvbn": "^4.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.8.3",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^5.3.0",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^5.3.0",
    "@storybook/addons": "^5.3.0",
    "@storybook/vue": "^5.3.0",
    "@types/chai": "^4.2.11",
    "@types/chai-as-promised": "^7.1.0",
    "@types/file-saver": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/js-cookie": "^2.2.0",
    "@types/json-server": "^0.14.0",
    "@types/mark.js": "^8.11.3",
    "@types/mocha": "^5.2.4",
    "@types/node": "^10.12.12",
    "@types/nprogress": "0.0.29",
    "@types/sinon-chai": "^3.2.1",
    "@types/webpack-env": "^1.13.6",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.2.3",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^4.2.3",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-e2e-nightwatch": "^3.3.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-pwa": "^3.0.5",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-typescript": "^4.2.3",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-vuex": "^4.2.3",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.2.3",
    "@vue/eslint-config-airbnb": "^5.0.2",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^5.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^4.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "babel-preset-vue": "^2.0.2",
    "eslint": "^5.16.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "file-loader": "^5.0.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.13.0",
    "prettier": "^1.18.2",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "typescript": "^3.0.0",
    "vue-svg-loader": "^0.12.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.17"
  }
}
```

I would appreciate every hint of how I can fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to upgrade? You may need to rollback your version of `cli-plugin-typescript` if you want to keep omitting the dot-vue extension (but I very much doubt this is a good idea). There appears to have been a breaking change after v4 where you now have to provide it. More info:

- https://cli.vuejs.org/migrating-from-v3/#vue-cli-plugin-typescript
- https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/pull/3909